# JavaScript: Divide array elements on space and add to same list

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JavaScript, let's say I have an array like this:
`["Foo", "Bar", "Baz Foo"]` and want to convert it into this: `["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Foo"]`.

In other words, split the array on space and add it as an extra element to the array. I feel like it should be some simple solution to this, but I just don't get it right. Does anyone know how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) along with [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```js
const arr = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz Foo"];
const res = arr.flatMap(x => x.split(" "));
console.log(res);
```

You could also use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to produce a string and then use `String#split`.

```js
const arr = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz Foo"];
const res = arr.join(' ').split(' ');
console.log(res);
```